# How to automate the triggering of mousedown event on html button using powershell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell, automation

I want to automate the process on a web application using PowerShell. However, I am not able to click on a button.

I looked into the inspect element and found that the event is bound to the jquery mousedown event.

So, I am wondering that this event is not triggered as I am clicking the button and event is bound to mousedown.

So, I just want to know to trigger the mousedown event on the HTML button.

Comment: Try `$("#button").click()` using `jQuery`

Comment: Have you any code to show? What you would do is: scrape the document, access the button through the DOM and then invoke .click() method.

Comment: @Snak3d0c - Click() performs the press(mousedown) as well as the release(mouseup). However, I only want to perform the press viz mousedown.